# MFC Serial Communications

Tags: c++, events, mfc, serial-port, serial-communication

I need to add serial port (e.g. COM8) communications to my MFC application.  Which APIs should I be looking at to do this?  I need it to be able to wait for n bytes to be in the receive queue before triggering (event, message, callback, etc.).  Is there a relatively simple way to do this?  All the examples I have looked at appear to use a polling mechanism for receive.  This will not work for my application.  There needs to be some sort of triggering mechanism that is triggered when there are n bytes in the queue.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overlapped I/O in Win32 works really well:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/serial_com.aspx

Also AFAIK, there are no official MFC class(es) for serial communications. (These could be easily wrapped though).